# 'Irregular' conformal mapping of square onto circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Assume that I want to find the conformal mapping from a square onto the unit disk. In the regular case, where the four edge points are positioned along cardinal directions, this mapping seems to have [a relatively simple solution](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1509/1509.06344.pdf). I have plotted this in the figure below (a).

The scenario I am interested in is a bit more complicated. I still want to map from a square (or rectangle) onto a disk, but I want to place the edge points of the square irregularly on the target circle (figure b). Assume that I know the positions of these target points.

Is it possible to find a mapping like this? If so, how would I go about solving this issue?

[image: Schematic illustration of my question, approximate; the original drawing can be found here https://i.stack.imgur.com/f17an.png]

Comment: I wonder if that “relatively simple solution” is really a conformal map.

Comment: Good point, Martin. I have exchanged it with a different source. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: Your top drawing is by no means conformal.

Comment: Yeah, I know - I did the best I could with Powerpoint, but my sketch is of course not angle-preserving. I'll try to make a better one. I hope it's enough to get the idea across, at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to asking if, given two quadruples $(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4)$ and $(w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4)$ of pairwise distinct points on the unit circle, there is a conformal map from the unit disk onto itself which extends continuously to the closed disk, and maps $z_k$ to $w_k$ for $k=1, 2, 3, 4$.

Conformal automorphisms of the unit disk are [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), they are uniquely determined by the images of three distinct points, preserve the [cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) and the orientation. Therefore such a mapping exists exactly if the cross-ratios $(z_1, z_2; z_3, z_4)$ and $(w_1, w_2; w_3, w_4)$ are equal, and if the two quadruples have the same orientation with respect to the unit disk. In that case the mapping $T$ is given by
$$
 (T(z), w_2; w_3, w_4) = (z, z_2; z_3, z_4) \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm not familiar with Möbius transformations yet. If I understand your answer correctly, you would suggest something like this: https://i.imgur.com/FflXfIql.png ? That is, to first map conventionally onto a unit disk, then to transform this into the desired irregular disk with a Möbius transformation?

Comment: @J.Galt: That is one possible approach, and has the advantage of “relatively” simple concrete formula. – Another way would be to determine the inverse of the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping from the “irregular” disk to the square, but that might be more complicated.

Comment: A brief question: After thinking some more, will the Möbius transformation really yield the desired transformation? The transformation I seek above is uniquely determined by four points, not three (the edge points) - so wouldn't the Möbius transformation be too simple, or do I misunderstand the approach?

Comment: @J.Galt: You *cannot* prescribe four target points arbitrarily. As I said, their cross-ration must be equal to that of the four source points (which is $2$ in your case). An automorphism of the unit disk is uniquely determined by the image of three points, and that determines the image of the fourth point.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, Martin - I think I got it! After experimenting a bit with Möbius transformations, I believe I could successfully reproduce the process you described. If you are curious, I uploaded the results here: https://i.imgur.com/FBCkRLR.png . The left subplot shows the original square, the centre subplot the conformal map to the unit circle, and the right subplot the Möbius transformation to my irregular disk. Your answer was really valuable, thanks once more!